# Parallelize GroupBy

Tags: parallelization, gathering

I have a huge list `longList` that I want to split into two parts depending on whether an element of the list satisfies the condition: `f[#]< 0.1` or not. My question is what is the most efficient way of doing this? The output should be two lists, the first one containing all elements of `longList` that satisfy the condition and the second one all the rest.

So far I've tried:

```
temp = GroupBy[longList, f[#] < 0.1 &];
{list1, list2} = {temp[True], temp[False]};
```

But it's not fast enough and if I wrap `GroupBy` in  `Parallelize` I get an error saying that it cannot be parallelized.

Comment: Maybe `Map[f[#] < 0.1 &, longList]` and `ParallelMap`?

Comment: Can you provide more information on what `f` is and what the list elements are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parallelize the application of the selector function, then use [`Pick`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html) to choose the elements for which the selector function returns `True`or `False`.

I made up a slow function `f` and a "long list":

```
f = (Pause[0.1]; # < 50) &;
longlist = RandomReal[{0, 100}, {10}];
```

You can appreciate the difference in application time between serial and parallel execution:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Map[f, longlist];]                      (* {1.01678, Null} *)
AbsoluteTiming[result = ParallelMap[f, longlist];]     (* {0.31652, Null} *)
```

You can then use `Pick` to split your list:

```
true =  Pick[longlist, result, True]
false = Pick[longlist, result, False]
```

You could also use [`Complement`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complement.html) to achieve the same, but it seems much slower than `Pick`:

```
false = Complement[longlist, true]
```

Comment: Thanks, this allowed me to parallelize and get the speed improvement I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

If the list contains numbers, I suggest vectorization instead of parallelization. Try to write `f` so that it is vectorizable.

My [BoolEval package](https://github.com/szhorvat/BoolEval) (partially available as [a resource function](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BoolEval)) is also convenient.

For example, if `f` is `Sin` (which is vectorized) then you can do

```
arr = RandomReal[100, 100000000];

<< BoolEval`

mask = BoolEval[Sin[arr] > 0.5]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {1.5, Null} *)

Pick[arr, mask, 1] // Length (* elements satisfying the condition *)
(* 33521172 *)

Pick[arr, mask, 0] // Length (* elements NOT satisfying the condition *)
(* 66478828 *)
```

If you only want one set of elements, a shorthand is

```
BoolPick[arr, Sin[arr] > 0.5]
```

I expect that no `Parallel*` function will be able to compete with this approach for as long as `f` is vectorizable.